# Is there a way to open the files that i filtered in the same pipeline and filter them again according to their content?

Tags: unix

I want to count all files from the home directory that have a name starting and ending with a number and contain (inside their content) the word “if”.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Mind describing, in English, the filenames or file contents that you would like to be emitted by your script? (What criteria should be used to filter names/contents?)

Answer (score 0):

I think the following should work

```sh
grep -l if $(ls [0-9]*[0-9]) | wc -l
```